# Converting int32 to int64 C#

Tags: c#, windows

I have problems with converting these two mentioned types. could somebody give me the solution please?

This is the code:

```
int INT32ID = int.Parse(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString());   
int StudentID = **Convert.ToInt64(INT32ID);**(here is the error)
var Student = DB.Students.Find(StudentID);
DB.Entry(Student).State = EntityState.Deleted;
```

And here is what the error says:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'long' to 'int'. An explicit conversion
> exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: The information you are probably missing is: `int` is a synonym for `Int32`, and `long` is a synonym for `Int64` (in C#, at least).

Answer (score 6):

```
int StudentID = Convert.ToInt64(INT32ID);
```

You are converting an int32 to an int64, and then *assigning it to a int32*. Since a int64 do not fit into a int32, you get an error. You should be able to just write:

```
long StudentID = INT32ID ;
```

or

```
var StudentID  = long.Parse(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString());
```

int32 is implicitly convertable to int64 since every 32 bit int can exactly be expressed as a 64 bit int, so there is no risk for data loss.

Answer (score 4):

Replace

```
int StudentID = ...
```

with

```
long StudentID = ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Your conversion is in wrong manner, Try it with  below code

```
var _studenID = long.Parse(_grdStudentDetails.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString());
```